# Javascript: window.open popup on every clicks

Tags: javascript, popup, blogs

I am using the below script to popup an url when some clicks my blog page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.body.onclick= function(){
window.open('https://mywebpage.com', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
}</script>
```

The issue , if u user clicks anywere in my blog mywebpage url  pops up,
as many times he clicks it keep on pops up,
i need just one time it should popup the webpage until his session ends from the browser

Comment: what about cookie?

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to have your onclick switch a boolean's value in one direction only, and have the window open when the boolean is switched.  Onclick activates with every click: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Also, this should be tagged javascript, not java.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the event listener from the handler to prevent any more clicks from calling the handler:

```
function openWindow(){
window.open('https://mywebpage.com', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
document.body.removeEventListener('click', openWindow);
}
document.body.addEventListener('click', openWindow);
```

So when the user first clicks, the popup will be opened, and the event listener will be removed, thus preventing the popup from triggering on further clicks.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply
i used your script like below but still pops up for evey new click
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWindow(){
window.open('https://mywebpage.com', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
document.body.removeEventListener('click', openWindow);
}
document.body.addEventListener('click', openWindow);
</script>

Comment: @striker What browser are you using? It works fine for me: http://www.iliveinabin.com/popup-test.html